# Displaying the time duration the app was in background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am new to iOS programming, and I am trying to make a very simple app to know more about the lifecycle and different states. The app will store the current timestamp when the app is running, and whenever it goes background and comes back up, it will show a message like "Good to see you after xx minutes".

Now, my approach is something like this, at the beginning there will be a timestamp stored in a variable, and when the viewDidLoad() method is called, it will check the timestamp with the current timestamp and display the subtracted value.

When the app is going background, I will change the value of the local timestamp variable in viewDidUnload() method and when is coming back up I will compare the timestamps and display the message.

Any pointers regarding the correct approach of doing this?

Comment: i think when app entered into background viewDidUnload() method not called .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code in your appdelegate.m file

put below method

```
-(void)minCalculation_backgroundtime:(NSString *)backgroundTime forgroundTime:(NSString *)foreGroundTime
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateformat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *lastDate = [dateformat dateFromString:foreGroundTime];
    NSDate *todaysDate = [dateformat dateFromString:backgroundTime];
    NSTimeInterval lastDiff = [lastDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSTimeInterval todaysDiff = [todaysDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSTimeInterval dateDiff = lastDiff - todaysDiff;
    int min = dateDiff/60;
    NSLog(@"Good to see you after %i minutes",min);
}
```

and replace below two methods

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *backGroundTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:backGroundTime forKey:@"backGroundTime"];
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *foreGroundTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSString *backGroundTime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"backGroundTime"];
    [self minCalculation_backgroundtime:backGroundTime forgroundTime:foreGroundTime];
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

try this your problem will solve

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults for saving last timestamp.

Use this function when your app is going in background

> ```
> - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
> - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
> - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
> ```

when app again open take out the difference of last saved timestamp with current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

create one Global variable and pass the data between viewControllers and keep your code in below methods..

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: But there will be a single viewController, right? So, I will create a new method called 'helloMessage' and will call the message from those two functions with appropriate parameters. Is this the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didEnterForeGround) name:UIApplicationDidEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

-(void)didEnterBackground
{
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [userDefaults setObject:[[NSDate alloc]init] forKey:@"TimeStamp"];
 [userDefaults synchronize];
}

-(void)didEnterForeGround
{
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *countString= [userDefaults objectForKey:@"TimeStamp"];  
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
 NSTimeInterval *timeBG=[[dateFormatter dateFromString:countString] timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate alloc] init]];
NSLog(@"Time Background: %@",timeBG);
}
```